# What is the function to display a legend for a scatter plot in python?

Tags: python, legend, scatter-plot

I'm trying to show the legend but it's not coming up.  There should be 4 legend items (one for each color).

You'll see there's a legend that begins with 1 letter but that's it?

I would be greatful for any help.  I've been searching online for ages.

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

#set dataframe
df = dataset

#colour dictionary
cdict = {
'Type1':2,
'Type2': 4,
'Type3':6, 
'Type4':8,
}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
dataset.plot(kind='scatter', 
x='Delta', 
y='Class', 
c=df['FTypes'].map(cdict),
)


plt.legend('FTypes')

#fit graph layout to screen
plt.tight_layout()

#add ref line
plt.axvline(x=0)

#show plot
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anrdh.png)

I've tried using ax.legend() and also plt.legend().

I may need to use handles but I'm not super familar with that yet.

Comment: If anyone else happens to be able to answer this question using matplotlib, I'd really like to learn how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember how to do this with matplotlib but you can easily do it with seaborn, which automatically adds legend when a categorical variable is used to add hue to points:

```
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(df, x='Delta', y='Class', hue='FTypes', ax=ax)

#fit graph layout to screen
plt.tight_layout()

#add ref line
plt.axvline(x=0)
```

Comment: I haven't really used seaborn before but it looks like I'll have to start learning because your solution worked! Thanks!